# Help - Thawed frozen Lasagne issues

Tags: food-safety

My wife purchased 2 M&M Family Frozen Meat Lasagnes and left them in a thermal freezer bag in the rear of the Escape. I found them two days later as I was taking her vehicle in for service, and they were thawed. Are these lasagnes still safe to eat if cooked, and if so, can they be refrozen? According to the ingredients the noodles are cooked and I assume the beef has been.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat)

Answer (score 2):

Per [Foodsafety.gov](http://www.foodsafety.gov/keep/charts/frozen_food.html), you can refreeze a casserole if it "still contains ice crystals and feels as cold as if refrigerated", but if "thawed and held above 40 °F for over 2 hours", it must be discarded.

Comment: Basically, if they aren't still a bit frozen in the middle, chuck them.

Answer (score -1):

Not re freezing food is more of a food safety standard than a rule. There is a type of bacteria called 'Super bacteria' which can be developed by constantly changing the temperature of bacteria. Personally I would fully cook the food and then either eat it or cool it quickly and freeze it. The worse thing to do is to leave it lingering in the hot/cold state.